# Accessing the status of browser media permissions

Tags: html5-video, webrtc, getusermedia

I am working on `getUserMedia` for accessing the webcam. But the problem is if user grants access to the camera at first and then in the middle it stops sharing the camera, the application fails.

so is there any way we can get the current status of browser media permissions to build conditions using it?

Comment: thw question is very vague, need some case...

Comment: the case is after loading the webpage for the first time, the browser will ask for permission to access the camera and if user accepts the permission, the page will load.
But now the problem is user can definitely choose to stop sharing the camera anytime middle in the application so the purpose of accessing the camera doesn't complete.
So I am asking that is there any way we can get the current permission status or change in permission status event?

Answer (score 0):

Once the user provides permission in `getUserMedia` api, you can use the stream for whatever purpose you need, also listen to the `inactive` event of the stream, once it gets triggered, you can try requesting the user for permission again, or notify user if you get permission denied error. `tl;dr` there is not much you can do if user denies access(, except notify him about the said issue and how it would affect his experience of accessing the app.)

Comment: can you give me some sample code so that I can get some idea. I tried to search but I am new to this field so not getting anything properly implemented.